# How to count different values in multiple elements

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

So I have multiple records with multiple Room Types and Room levels i know this code is working so far but i was hoping someone can show me an easier way ?

this is the XML i'm getting

```
<RETS ReplyCode="0" ReplyText="Operation Success.">                     
<DELIMITER value = "09"/>                       
<COLUMNS>   InputEntryOrder listing_MUI matrix_unique_id    RoomLevel   RoomType    </COLUMNS>
<DATA>  1   74743676    74743677    U   A   </DATA>
<DATA>  2   74743676    74743678    M   N   </DATA>
<DATA>  3   74743676    74743679    L   A   </DATA>
<DATA>  4   74743676    74743680    L   N   </DATA>
<DATA>  5   74743676    74743681    U   A   </DATA>
<DATA>  6   74743676    74743682    M   BF  </DATA>
<DATA>  7   74743676    74743683    M   E   </DATA>
<DATA>  8   74743676    74743684    M   J   </DATA>
<DATA>  9   74743676    74743685    U   A   </DATA>
<DATA>  10  74743676    74743686    M   H   </DATA>
<DATA>  11  74743676    74743687    M   K   </DATA>
<DATA>  12  74743676    74743688    M   N   </DATA>
<DATA>  13  74743676    74743689    U   N   </DATA>
<DATA>  14  74743676    74743690    M   N   </DATA>
</RETS>
```

And this is the C# code i have working so far, but not happy with :(

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<root>" + ResponseText + "</root>");
    XmlNode mlsNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//RETS");

    //bool MasterBedroom = false;
    int UtilityRoomCountM = 0;
    int UtilityRoomCountU = 0;
    int UtilityRoomCountL = 0;
    int UtilityRoomCountG = 0;

    int DwellingUnitU = 0;
    int DwellingUnitM = 0;
    int DwellingUnitL = 0;

    foreach (XmlNode node in mlsNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (node.Name == "DATA")
        {
            string[] splitData = node.InnerText.Split("\t".ToCharArray());
            string ResponseD = node.InnerText;
            RoomName = splitData[10];
            RoomValue = splitData[8];

                switch (RoomName)
                {
                    case "M":
                        if (RoomName == "N")
                            UtilityRoomCountU++;
                        else
                            DwellingUnitU++;
                        break;
                    case "L":
                        if (RoomName == "N")
                            UtilityRoomCountM++;
                        else
                            DwellingUnitM++;
                        break;
                    case "U":
                        if (RoomName == "N")
                            UtilityRoomCountL++;
                        else
                            DwellingUnitL++;
                        break;
                }

            }
    }
    // outside the loop
    // Do the Utiltiy Room Here so you can count
    // these are other fucntion which just set's the value back to my forms
    SetField("UtilityRoomUpper", UtilityRoomCountU.ToString());
    SetField("UtilityRoomMain", UtilityRoomCountM.ToString());
    SetField( "UtilityRoomLower", UtilityRoomCountL.ToString());
    SetField( "UtilityRoomGarage", UtilityRoomCountG.ToString());

    SetField("DwellingUnitUpper", DwellingUnitU.ToString());
    SetField("DwellingUnitMain", DwellingUnitM.ToString());
    SetField("DwellingUnitLower", DwellingUnitL.ToString());
```

i was hope instead of declaring so many counters , away where i can find all Room Types of values of N and how many M ( main ) , L ( lower ), U (upper) and same goes for other room types like A !

Comment: I see `switch (RoomName)` then `if (RoomName` - is that right?

Comment: yes the idea was if RoomName = n then count else if roomname = A then count else if Roomname = BF then then count , and so on , i'm doing different count for each room Name and how many entries are found in each level , does that help

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not positive this is better than what you have, but you could create an array of arrays and do a select action on it and get a count from there.

Comment: This is not an answer.. this should be a comment, not to mention you don't provide and example or alternative to support the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a class to represent each record say "Room".

```
public class Room
        {
            public string RoomType;
            public string RoomLevel;

        }
```

Create object for the class in the loop set the properties and add it to the list.

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)

```
        {
            Room r = new Room();
            string[] splitters = new string[] { @" " };
            r.RoomLevel = node.InnerText.Split(splitters, StringSplitOptions.None)[3];
            r.RoomType = node.InnerText.Split(splitters, StringSplitOptions.None)[5];
            roomList.Add(r);
        }
```

Then you can count whatever the logic you want by filtering from the list

```
//Apply the logic whatever yuo want 
                roomList.Count(r => r.RoomLevel == "M" && r.RoomType == "L");
```

Comment: change split characters and column index based on your requirement